# Base Number Arithmetic

Tags: number-systems

[image]

I got no idea how to solve that problem. What I have done so far is I have randomly guessed numbers. I wanted to know a faster way to solve it in the future, just in case of some even more complex cases.

Comment: On this site, you should definitely show what you've done so far. This isn't wolfram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I.e. solve $(b-1)^2=3b+1$, $\,b\in\{4,5,\ldots,9\}$ (because $3$ has to be a valid digit in base $b$).

$$\iff b^2-2b+1=3b+1\iff b^2=5b\iff b=5$$

Comment: ok, your edit changed you words out of latex. But I think I get the idea. You change P into b-1 right?

Comment: @Houdineo Indeed. And so the answer is $P=4,\, b=5$.